# How to setup a dynamic gitlab-ci file

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I’m trying to setup a dynamic gitlab-ci file that includes the needed gitlab-ci file based on a project variable.

Unfortunately I can’t seem to get this to work, i’ve read the documentation and searched the forum but unfortunately I can’t find any solutions.

How do I achieve a dynamic gitlab-ci file ?

Essentially I wanted to do something like the snippet below but I noticed I couldn’t use variables in the file method ( Returns “Invalid config: File does not exist”. ).

```
include:
  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-$GITLABFILE.yml'
    only:
      - $GITLABFILE
include:
  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci.yml'
    only:
      - $GITLABFILE == null
```

Since I couldn’t use a variable in the file method i tried the below config but unfortunately it always loads the last file and ignores the only keyword.

```
include:
  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci.yml'
    except:
      variables:
        - $GITLABFILE

  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-legacy.yml'
    only:
      variables:
        - $GITLABFILE == 'legacy'

  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-legacy-nobuild.yml'
    only:
      variables:
        - $GITLABFILE == 'legacy-nobuild'
```

I expect a single gitlab-ci file that can retrieve other gitlab-ci files based on a variable.

Hopefully someone can help me out or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put conditional logics inside these individual gitlab-ci files, and then just include them all.

Something like this - in your main file:

```
variables:
  GITLABFILE: legacy

include:
  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci.yml'

  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-legacy.yml'

  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-legacy-nobuild.yml'
```

And then in each sub-files - e.g. in `gitlab-ci-legacy.yml`:

```
job:
  script:
    - echo Do something
  only:
    variables:
      - $GITLABFILE == "legacy"
```

See more: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyvariablesexceptvariables

Comment: Thanks Ivan this looks like a possible solution, i'll try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ivan I found the perfect solution, what i've done is create 1 gitlab-ci that includes all others and within each specific file I used the only keyword like Ivan suggested.

Now my files look like this:

The gitlab-ci that is present on project level ( in each project ):

```
include:
  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/selector.yml'
```

Then my selector.yml file looks like this:

```
include:
  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-global.yml'

  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-nobuild.yml'

  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-legacy.yml'

  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-multitheme.yml'

  - project: 'tools/gitlab-ci'
    file: '/gitlab-ci-default.yml'
```

Since all files are being read, I had to move my before_script tasks to each individual stage otherwise gitlab only read the last before_script declaration, so I created a template/anchor for this:

```
.before_script_template: &before-script-legacy
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -y && apt-get install -yqqf openssh-client git unzip sshpass rsync --fix-missing

    # Is probably already present but just to be sure.
    - npm install -g gulp
    - npm install -g bower

    - echo "You've set the GITLABFILE var to legacy and therefore get this file"

compile_legacy:
  stage: build
  <<: *before-script-legacy
  script:
    - #Some stuff here....
  only:
    variables:
      - $GITLABFILE == "legacy" && $SKIP_COMPILE == null
```

Also note that each stage has to have a unique identifier/job name!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution: see [GitLab 14.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/09/22/gitlab-14-3-released/#include-gitlab-cicd-configuration-based-on-conditions) (September 2021)

> ### Include GitLab CI/CD configuration based on conditions
>
> [`include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#include) is one of the most popular keywords to use when writing a full CI/CD pipeline.
> If you are building larger pipelines, you are probably using the `include` keyword to bring external YAML configuration into your pipeline.
>
> In this release, we are expanding the power of the keyword so you can use `include` with [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#include) conditions.
>
> Now, you can decide when external CI/CD configuration should or shouldn’t be included. This will help you write a standardized pipeline with the ability to dynamically modify itself based on the conditions you choose.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_3/conditional_include.png -- Include GitLab CI/CD configuration based on conditions]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules-with-include) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/276515).

Example:

> You can only use `if` rules in `include`, and only with [certain variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#variables-with-include).
> `rules` keywords such as `changes` and `exists` are not supported.

```yaml
include:
  - local: builds.yml
    rules:
      - if: '$INCLUDE_BUILDS == "true"'

test:
  stage: test
  script: exit 0
```

---

See [GitLab 14.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/11/22/gitlab-14-5-released/#conditional-includes-with-exists-keyword) (November 2021)

> ### Conditional includes with exists keyword
>
> The `include` keyword is one of the most popular ones to use when writing a full CI/CD pipeline. If you are building larger pipelines, you
> are probably using the `include` keyword to bring external YAML configuration into your pipeline.
>
> In this release, we are expanding the power of the keyword so you can use include with `exists` in the rules condition. Now, you
> can decide when external CI/CD configuration should or shouldn’t be included based on when certain files exist in the repository.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/14_5/rules_include.png -- Conditional includes with exists keyword]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#use-rules-with-include) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/341511).